# visualizing the dynamic data of a SQL database

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to catch dynamic datas from a database and visualize it as a water level,
this is the code line of the data in `PHP`:

```
$d.= '"fillevel":'. $row[2];
```

and the one in `html` in  :

```
$('#flvl').text(msg.fillevel);
```

How can I make this data the dynamic hieght of a square for showwing the Level of a water tank?
the data is in real format, snapshot: 10.6838535478

I'd be happy, if you could help.
Best Regards

Comment: Can you define `$row`?. Also, your mixing JavaScript with PHP.

Comment: the $row[2] in PHP part fetches the content of the second row for the user (me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to initialize a database connection, for this purpose i will use `PDO`:

`$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databaseName', 'user', 'password');`

With this `$db` object we can now prepare and execute queries.

```
//The query to execute (fill in your query here for getting the square height)
$query = "SELECT ... FROM ...";

//Prepare the query
$statement = $db->prepare($query);

//Execute the query
$statement->execute();

//Fetch the queries result
$row = $statement->fetch();
```

The  [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) function will return a single row based on the query. You can now call your data from the `$row` object with something like this in your PHP file:

```
echo $row[2];
```

---

### Showing this inside a HTML document

Lets say you have a `index.php` inside your website folder with this inside:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Your Website</title>
</head>

<body>
   <p>Some text!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

You simply put a opening and closing php tag inside the body area like this:

```
<body>
   <p>Some text!</p>

   <?php

   ?>
</body>
```

And write your PHP code inside of those tags, in this case, this will be:

```
//The query to execute (fill in your query here for getting the square height)
$query = "SELECT ... FROM ...";

//Prepare the query
$statement = $db->prepare($query);

//Execute the query
$statement->execute();

//Fetch the queries result
$row = $statement->fetch();
```

All together, it would look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Your Website</title>
</head>

<body>
   <p>Some text!</p>
   </br>

   <?php
$query = "SELECT ... FROM ...";

//Prepare the query
$statement = $db->prepare($query);

//Execute the query
$statement->execute();

//Fetch the queries result
$row = $statement->fetch();

//Print an item from the $row array
echo $row[2];
   ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Bas for your answer. I have the connection with data base already. I just want to visualize it now. But I don't know how

Comment: @point_system Sorry, i didn't know that. Editing my post right now :)

Comment: @point_system Go to www.codeshare.io and paste your code there. And then paste the link here :)

Comment: you got it? don't hesitate to ask about it

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
    $('#flvl').css("height", msg.fillevel * 10);

Comment: I have tried your code but I don't get anything after refreshing :(

Comment: this '#flvl' is what element? should be div. Give it a color. Try without * 10.

Comment: in PHP I fetch the value of fillevel :$d.= '"fillevel":'. $row[2];
and in html(js) I use $('#flvl').text(msg.fillevel); to have a variable